# How to use WordPress to create a website that is more than just blog

Tags: wordpress, themes

I am pretty new to WordPress. I know how to use WordPress to create a blog, or a website that just contains blog. I want to know how to use WordPress to create a website that is more like a website than just a blog, although the real content of each page is just each blog. The website will be just about content, and will not be interactive other than some comment or contact us forms.

What I want to achieve is:

- I can post blog to it, this is where all the content of the website comes from.
- The website will have several sub-categories. Let's pretend that I am
  going to build a website about DIY projects, and I want the website
  look like this:

  ```
           Welcome to My DIY Website          <--- this is a banner at the top of home page

     House Project      Car Project    Furniture    Appliances Repair   Tools   Blog    About Me

     Some content on home page, cold be just excerpt from recent post, etc, or a special message
     or announcement I want to put on home page.
  ```

When user clicks on each of the menu "House Project", "Car Project" etc, it will lead to a page that will list all posts related to those subjects. When people clicks on "Blog", the web page will be displayed just like a blog which list posts chronically.

When I make a post, I can assign it to one or more categories, and that post will appear under that one or multiple categories. For example, I make a post about using a special tool for a house project, that post may appear under both "House Project" and "Tools".

How do I achieve such goal? For "About Me" or "Contact Us" kind of link in the menu, I know they are called "page" in WordPress. But what about the others sub-categories in the menu?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

As a newbie, its more easier for you to use pagebuilders like Elementor. There are several templates available in elementor which you can just insert in your site and then edit it simply refer to its tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and I am using Elementor. But your reply didn't answer my original question, which is how to create website kind of features (i.e. the sub-categories menus kind of thing). My original question is not about how to build an individual post or page.